# Error while calling SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway.invoke method

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

This is my first attempt to invoke a SOAP web service using Spring Integration. Below is my bean config class.

```
    @Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource(value = { "application.properties" })
public class SoapGatewayConfiguration {

    /**
     * URL mappings used by WS endpoints
     */
    public static final String[] WS_URL_MAPPINGS = { "/services/*", "*.wsdl", "*.xsd" };
    public static final String GATEWAY_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME = "wsGatewayInboundChannel";
    public static final String GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME = "wsGatewayOutboundChannel";

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory f = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        f.setPort(9000);
        return f;
    }

    /**
     * Register the servlet mapper, note that it uses MessageDispatcher
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        servlet.setTransformSchemaLocations(true);
        servlet.setPublishEvents(true);
        ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> servletDef = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet,
                WS_URL_MAPPINGS);
        servletDef.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletDef;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new Direct channels to handle the messages
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel wsGatewayInboundChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel wsGatewayOutboundChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
    }

    /**
     * Startup the WebServiceInboundGateway Endpoint, this will handle the incoming
     * SOAP requests and place them onto the request channel
     */
    @Bean
    @Gateway
    public SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway(
            @Value("${spring.ws.request.timeout:1000}") long requestTimeout,
            @Value("${spring.ws.reply.timeout:1000}") long replyTimeout,
            @Value("${spring.ws.should.track:true}") boolean shouldTrack) {
        SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway wsg = new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway();
        wsg.setRequestChannel(wsGatewayInboundChannel());
        wsg.setReplyChannel(wsGatewayOutboundChannel());
        wsg.setExtractPayload(false); // Send the full RAW SOAPMessage and not just payload
        wsg.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        wsg.setShouldTrack(shouldTrack);
        wsg.setReplyTimeout(replyTimeout); // Do not believe this prop supported currently
        wsg.setRequestTimeout(requestTimeout); // Do not believe this prop is supported currently
        wsg.setCountsEnabled(true);
        return wsg;
    }

    /**
     * You must enable debug logging on
     * org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor
     * to see the logs from this interceptor
     */
    @Bean
    public EndpointInterceptor soapMessageLoggingInterceptor() {
        SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor li = new SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor();
        li.setLogRequest(true);
        li.setLogResponse(true);
        li.setLogFault(true);
        return li;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the incoming web service against the schema
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Bean
    public AbstractValidatingInterceptor payloadValidatingInterceptor(XsdSchema xsdSchema,
            @Value("${spring.ws.soap.validate.request:true}") boolean soapValidateRequest,
            @Value("${spring.ws.soap.validate.reply:true}") boolean soapValidateResponse,
            @Value("${spring.ws.soap.validate.addErrorDetail:true}") boolean soapAddValidationErrorDetail

    ) throws IOException {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor interceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setXsdSchema(xsdSchema);
        interceptor.setValidateRequest(soapValidateRequest);
        interceptor.setValidateResponse(soapValidateResponse);
        return interceptor;
    }

    /**
     * Map the allowable service Uri's.
     */
    @Bean
    public EndpointMapping uriEndpointMapping(PayloadValidatingInterceptor payloadValidatingInterceptor,
            SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway,
            SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor) {
        UriEndpointMapping mapping = new UriEndpointMapping();
        mapping.setUsePath(true);
        mapping.setDefaultEndpoint(webServiceInboundGateway(1000L, 1000L, true));
        // mapping.setInterceptors({loggingInterceptor, payloadValidatingInterceptor});
        return mapping;
    }


    @Bean
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("employees.wsdl.xml"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    /**
     * Expose the xsd at http://localhost:8080/services/mySchema.xsd
     **/
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema mySchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("Employee.xsd"));
    }
}
```

I doubt that I am making some mistake while creating the soap request. Below is the code snippet where I am creating the soap request

```
SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway employeeSearchInboundGateway = context
        .getBean(SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway.class);
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
SaajSoapMessageFactory saaj = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(messageFactory);

String requestXML = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:myNamespace=\"http://www.springpoc.com/employee-ws\">"
        + " <SOAP-ENV:Header/> " + " <SOAP-ENV:Body> "
        + " <findEmployeeByIdRequest>  <employeeId>12345</employeeId> </findEmployeeByIdRequest> "
        + " </SOAP-ENV:Body> " + " </SOAP-ENV:Envelope> ";

SaajSoapMessage request = new SaajSoapMessage(messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(),
        new ByteArrayInputStream(requestXML.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()))));
SoapEnvelope soapEnvelope = request.getEnvelope();

SoapHeader header = request.getSoapHeader();

String myNamespace = "myNamespace";
String myNamespaceURI = "http://www.springpoc.com/employee-ws";
soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);

MessageContext arg0 = new DefaultMessageContext(request, saaj);
employeeSearchInboundGateway.invoke(arg0);
```

I am getting error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SaajSoapMessage findEmployeeByIdRequest, headers={ws_soapAction="", replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@73163d48, history=webServiceInboundGateway, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@73163d48, id=d40a8603-903c-d5a5-b7a8-96177d1f4114, timestamp=1525316363103}]
```

**Question:**

Need advise that do we need to set the **replyChannel & errorChannel** properties in the SOAP request header? If yes, then please let me know how to do it.

**Edit 1:**
Below is the configuration of **@ServiceActivator** endpoint

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "wsGatewayOutboundChannel")
public void makeCall(Message<Employee> pr) {
    Employee response = pr.getPayload();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that there is something subscribed to the `wsGatewayInboundChannel`. That’s where you get that exception from.

In other words the WS Inbound Gateway sends a message to the channel, but there is nothing to handle it on the other side of the channel.

Comment: Hello Artem, I do have a @ServiceActivator endpoint configured to listen to **wsGatewayOutboundChannel** channel which is configured as the reply channel in the **SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway** bean (as in **Edit 1**). In the error message its complaining that there is no listener to TemporaryReplyChannel. I was assuming that It would say no subscriber for **wsGatewayOutboundChannel** 

Please help me understand how should I configure the **SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway** to get the response of the SOAP service.

Comment: Well, but I’m talking about `wsGatewayInboundChannel` - the place where this gateway sends messages. Essentially you don’t need the reply channel at all, because this is the place where WS gateway is waiting for reply, but doesn’t send. At all.